# jQuery parseJSON returns double data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a PHP file which returns this:

```
$data = pg_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in the .js code i do this:

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(text);
console.dir(jsonObj);
```

And my problem is I get this "double" data:

{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"test","type":"test","2":"google","name":"google", "3":"http://www.google.com","url":"http://www.google.com"}

Any ideas on how to retrieve it without those indexes (0,1,2...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in parseJSON method but in pg_fetch_array. And it is the expected behaviour.

PHP Documentation says that [pg_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) by default "indexed numerically (beginning with 0) or associatively (indexed by field name)" so you can access values either by index or by name.

To change this behaviour, use either

```
$data = pg_fetch_array($result, 0, PGSQL_ASSOC); //Keys are names only
$data = pg_fetch_array($result, 0, PGSQL_NUM); //Keys are indexes only
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to parse that using json, if you are using jquery ajax method then just mention dataTye: json, then you can directly access that object.

Comment: Manne: It's the same thing even if I put that dataType.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);